# Ubuntu 16.04 external monitors black screen "Could not set the configuration for CRTC"

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have a Dell Latitude E5450 with a docking station k07a002 and 2 external monitors hp v241p.

Everything was working fine until I upgraded kernel to my current:

```
Linux Latitude-E5450 4.4.0-77-generic #98-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 26 08:34:02 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Since then, when I start my laptop as usually straight plugged into the docking, after longing in I get

```
 ERROR : could not set the configuration for CRTC 64
```

and all my screens go blank.

The only way I have screens working is turning on my laptop (without the docking) and plugging into the docking already logged into ubuntu. Everything works fine this way except if I press "Win-key + L" to lock my session. After that, screens go blank again.

xrandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +  59.93    48.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       60.00  
DP1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1-3 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       60.00  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

sudo lshw -c video

```
 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:48 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

lspci | grep VGA

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
```

X -version

```
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux Latitude-E5450 4.4.0-77-generic #98-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 26 08:34:02 UTC 2017 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-77-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=7ff3a21b-4b0c-4898-8be1-7903408c7244 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 02 November 2016  10:06:10PM
xorg-server 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
```

Thank you

Comment: I have the same issue with a laptop with two video outputs.  The problem is usually the graphics card on the system, which also has to support the docking station - it doesn't support more than two monitors.

Comment: @ThomasWard the thing is that all my 3 screens (the physical one + the 2 external monitors) have been working just fine for about 2 years until my last kernel upgrade :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. A temporary solution consisted in going back to a previous working version of the kernel: 4.4.0-72-generic for me. Been following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763928/how-to-set-previous-kernel-as-default-in-grub-grub-customizer) to do so.

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to [flag](/help/privileges/flag-posts) this question as a duplicate of the other once you [earned 15 reputation](/help/whats-reputation). Don't forget to vote for the answer(s) there that you found useful!

Comment: @DavidFoerster I think the link is not the essential part, the essential part is downgrading to a working kernel with a specific version. I think it's different