# Linux 4.18.0-14 won't boot

Tags: boot, kernel

I did a software update on my Aser Aspire 1830T-68U118 and it installed Linux 4.18.0-14 but after doing a restart it doesn't even get to ask me for my password, just stops. After much googling (fortunately I had a bootable usb stick) i used the "press shift" and made it boot into 4.18.0-13 . Is there a anything I can do or do I just wait for the next available Linux update to see if it solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a kernel bug existing for the current upgrade - see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1813657

Meanwhile, you can set grub to default to a prior kernel, via either

[How to set previous kernel as default in GRUB (Grub customizer)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763928/how-to-set-previous-kernel-as-default-in-grub-grub-customizer)

or

[Set "older" kernel as default grub entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry)

Comment: Note to close voters:  I am aware that this is a link-only answer, but for the sake of brevity for those affected by the kernel bug I would prefer not to ask those users to look around for how to set grub.

Comment: Thanks, I'll just set GRUB and see what happens with the next drop.